# C++ Macro replaces needed member function

Tags: c++

I have a problem in the following line (and several other similar ones):

```cpp
std::vector<uint8_t> decodeTable(128, std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max());
```

`std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max()` is a member function.
However, somewhere in another header, `max()` is defined as a macro. As a result, it is seen as a call to the macro and the scope just causes a syntax error, plus an error because there weren't enough arguments passed into the macro.

I'm wondering if there's a way around that?
I'm trying to get a pre-existing library to run so I can't just rewrite everything in a different way.

Comment: Is this on Windows and you are including `windows.h` somehow?

Comment: @user17732522 It is indeed on windows, macro is defined in minwindef.h

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, thank you. I already tried NOMINMAX and it didn't work, but the trick with parentheses seems to have fixed it.

Comment: You need to define `NOMINMAX` before you include `windows.h` or `minwindef.h`.